# Google Test on a local function that calls another function

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a class that I want to test.

```
class Myclass {
      virtual int functionA (int x) {
          if (x==1) {
             functionB();
             return 1;
          }
          else return 0;
      }
      virtual void functionB() {
          // do some logic
          functionC();
          printf ("functionB \n"};
      }
      virtual void functionC() {
          // do some logic
          printf ("functionC \n"};
      }
}
```

I setup a Mock class:

```
    class MockMyClass : public Myclass {
          MOCKMETHOD1(functionA, int(int x));
          MOCKMETHOD0(functionB, void());
          MOCKMETHOD0(functionC, void());
    }
```

My test case in test class:

```
    class MyTesting : public testing::Test {
          virtual void SetUp(){
              testObj = new MyClass();
              testMock = new MockMyClass();
          }
          virtual void Teardown() {
              delete testObj;
              delete testMock;
          }
    }
    MyClass * testObj;
    MockMyClass * testMock;
    TEST_F (MyClass, Test1){
        EXPECT_CALL (testMock, functionB());
        testObj->functionA() 
    }
    TEST_F (MyClass, Test2){
        EXPECT_CALL (testMock, functionC());
        testObj->functionB() 
    }
    TEST_F (MyClass, Test3){
        EXPECT_CALL (testMock, functionC());
        testObj->functionC() 
    }
```

Basically, I need to run the functionA -> functionB -> functionC.

How can write Test1 such that when have expect call of functionB, it doesn't "go further" into B and requires another expect call of function C.

In other words, how can write a Test1 such that whatever logic in functionB will be tested in Test2 and further in Test3 and Test1 just expect a call of functionB.

Answer (score 1):

```
TEST_F (MyClass, Test1) {
    InSequence seq;
    EXPECT_CALL (MockMyClass, functionB());
    EXPECT_CALL (MockMyClass, functionC());
    testObj->functionA(1);
}
```

[InSequence](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#OrderedCalls)

Your example will not compile,  functionA requires arg and missing semicolons.

Comment: I think I have a problem with this. The test fails because of error:  "Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL". I think the functionB, and functionC are called by the same object that calls functionA,. Thus when I put "MockMyClass", in there, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please care of your example is compiled. Too much errors. After you make it compiled, I show you a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong use of inheritance is main problem here.

If your class under test is same as mock class then this should be obvious something wrong is here.

Note that here:

```cpp
virtual void SetUp() {
    testObj = new MyClass();
    testMock = new MockMyClass();
}
```

there is no dependency between `testObj` and `testMock`. So Question is how `testObje` can impact state of `testMock`? It can't!

So basically problem is your code design of production code (code under test).

Since logic of this class has been obfuscated I have no clues how I could fix your code properly. I'm guessing it should be something like this:

```cpp
class ISomeDependency {
public:
    virtual int functionA(int x) = 0;
};

//---------

class Myclass {
public:
    Myclass(ISomeDependency& dep)
        : mDep { dep }
    {
    }

    void functionB()
    {
        if (mDep.function(1) > 5) {
            functionC();
        }
    }
    void functionC()
    {
    }

private:
    ISomeDependency& mDep;
};
```

```cpp
class MyclassTest : public ::testing::Test {

    void checkMyClassIsInStateX()
    {
        ASSERT_EQ(myClass.getX(), ...);
    }

public:
    MockSomeDependency mock;
    Myclass myClass { mock };
};

TEST_F(MyclassTest, functionBCallsDependencyWithOneAndChangesStateToX)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, functionA(1)).WillOnce(Return(4));
    myClass.functionB();
    checkMyClassIsInStateX();
}
```